# Angular error using mat-sidenav element (material UI), when navigating from one component to another

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I will be extremely thankful if you can help me to solve this problem that I have trying to tackle and I couldn't find information about it. I'm trying to navigate from one view to another but as soon I use the <a> nested in a <mat-sidenav>, I have this error: "Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character". The error output points to "app.component.html:22"

Console Error Reference:

**"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character"**

```
Here, the app.component.html , the app.component.ts , the app-routing.module.ts, and the app.module.ts


+++ app.component.html +++

<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z4">
  <span>
    <button mat-mini-fab (click)="sidenav?.toggle()">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span class="logo">
      <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
    </span>
    <span class="title">
      {{ title }}
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button class="login" mat-mini-fab>
    <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened class="app-sidenav">
    <nav>
      <a
        mat-button
        class="nav-link"
        *ngFor="let link of links"
        [routerLink]="link.path"
        routerLinkActive="active"
      >
        <mat-icon>{{ link.icon }}</mat-icon>
        {{ link.title }}
      </a>
    </nav>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>


+++ app.component.ts +++

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title: string = 'Angular 13 Fundamentals';

  links: Array<{ path: string; icon: string; title: string }> = [
    { path: '/home', icon: 'home', title: 'Home' },
    { path: '/courses', icon: 'view_list', title: 'Courses' },
  ];

  constructor() {}
}


+++ app-routing.module.ts +++

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'courses', component: CoursesComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }


 +++ app.module.ts +++

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses/courses.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, CoursesComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I expect to navigate between the components without problem and all the elements being rendered properly. I dont' have any compilation error, the only one that pops-up is the mentioned one as soon I try to navigate to the other element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After troubleshooting on different browsers, I found that by some reason the prettier config was strangely inserting a breaking space on [(ngModel)] so it was compiled as: [( ngModel )], hence the property settings resulted in a runtime error.

Cheers!